# How to run command in Netbean IDE

Tags: php, laravel

Recently learning Laravel using netbean IDE, I saw some command like

```
cygcheck -c cygwin

composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

but i don know how I can run them, tried to run in CMD, but the file generate in different location and php `php artisan ide-helper:generate` is not supported.

Comment: you have to run the command inside your project directory (You can use CMD, or you can use the netbeans built in terminal which can be found here: Window->IDE Tools->Terminal )